# Using an ellipse as a threshold for Nearest function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering, nearest

The `Nearest` function can receive as a threshold parameter a radius to look for elements inside that. [From the documentation:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html)

> ```
> Nearest[data,x,{n,r}] give up to the n nearest elements to x within a radius r
> ```

What about if instead of a circle I want to use an ellipse as a threshold? So I would have an X and Y limit for the `Nearest` function.

I know that `Nearest` can receive a `DistanceFunction` as a parameter but I can't think of how to use that for this purpose.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you are asking is not quite clear, which may be why you are confused about the usage of distance function. You want the exclude points outside an ellipse (threshhold), but  how to rank inside points is an independent criteria.  Bills answer gives one interpretation.

Comment: The DistanceFunction seems the way to go. However you may also want to rescale your dataset so that the ellipse constraint becomes a circle constraint.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest solution is to rescale the data.  Suppose we have a distance limit of $r_x = 2$ and $r_y = 1$ and a point set

```
data = {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...}
```

Instead of working with `data` and these two radii, work with a single radius $r=1$ and the dataset

```
dataScaled = {{0.5 x1, y1}, {0.5 x2, y2}, ...}
```

Finally, transform the results back to the original coordinate system.

This can be generalized for arbitrary affine transformations, including rotations.

For example, let's assume that the ellipse is rotated 30 degrees and it has dimensions 2 and 1.  This can be obtained from a circle by using the following transformation matrix:

```
backtrafo = N[RotationMatrix[30*Degree] . {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

Let's visualize it!

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Circle[], AffineTransform[backtrafo]], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

We need to apply the reverse transformation of this on our data and use the result in `Nearest`:

```
trafo = Inverse[backtrafo];

Nearest[trafo.# & /@ data -> data, trafo.point, {n, 1}]
```

This will give us the all the points within the rotated ellipse drawn around `point`.

---

Let's test the method visually.  Generate some points:

```
data = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {100, 2}];
```

Find the points within the ellipse centred on the origin:

```
pointsWithin = Nearest[trafo.# & /@ data -> data, trafo.{0, 0}, {Infinity, 1}];
```

And finally visualize all points together with the ellipse:

```
Graphics[{ 
  GeometricTransformation[Circle[], AffineTransform[backtrafo]], 
  Point[data], {Red, Point[pointsWithin]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

Technical comment: An advantage of this method compared to using a `DistanceFunction` is that a custom `DistanceFunction` will prevent `Nearest` from using a very efficient [quad-tree data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9463165/695132), and it will resort to a much slower pairwise-distance calculation.

---

Thanks to **Michael E2** for suggestion on simple and efficient code!

Comment: @MichaelE2 You mean scale back the results?

Comment: Hmm, what about a tilted ellipse? I guess one would multiply the data by the inverse matrix representing the rotation and scaling...

Comment: @Ajasja Yes, exactly.  The OP was asking for different radii along the $x$ and $y$ axes so I didn't include that.  Generally, any affine transformation (and then reverse transformation) should work.

Comment: @Szabolcs  I meant scale `x`.  Something like `Nearest[trafo.data -> data, trafo.x, {n, 1}]`. Scaling back might be more efficient, unless many calls to a `NearestFunction` are to be used.  (Still I think `x` needs to be scaled, right?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks!  Finally I've gotten around to fixing it up :)

Comment: I know one shouldn't use the comments to say thanx but..thanx a lot! Just one thing, when normalizing the data, will I lose any significant precision because of internal rounding or something similar?

Comment: @xtian777x I believe that that precision loss is truly negligible.  Machine precision numbers give you 15-16 significant digits. The data that's returned is going to be the precisely same as the original when using the syntax `Nearest[transformedData -> data, ...]`.  So the very minor numerical errors only factor in the distance calculation but won't affect the data points that are returned.

Answer (score 5):

`DistanceFunction` is one way to go. For example, the code below generates a random set of points in the box with all elements drawn from -1 to 1 and then selects the 20 points that are closest to the point {0.5, 0} (in the sense of an ellipse defined by the matrix `a`). In the example, `a` is tall and skinny, but could have any orientation and scale.

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
a = {{2, 0}, {0, 1/2}};
f[x_, y_] := Norm[a.(x - y)];
nf = Nearest[data, {0.5, 0}, 20, DistanceFunction -> f];
ListPlot[nf, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The only issue with `DistanceFunction` is that for custom functions the performance is much worse than for the standard euclidian distance, so a combination with @halirutan´s approach may be more performant for large sets.

Comment: @Yves, bill: One could transform the data so the ellipse maps to a circle, use the standard Euclidean distance there, and transform the results back.

Comment: @RahulNarain sounds like a good plan for such distance functions - looking forward to your answer :D

Comment: @Yves: I had to go to bed. I'm happy to see that Szabolcs has taken care of it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess one method would be to take the larger radius of your ellipse to collect all possible candidates with

```
Nearest[data,x,{n,r}]
```

and after that filter them with e.g. `Select` to find all points that are inside your ellipse.